# Using powerquery M code data wrangling, how to fill in missing value from grouped rows

Tags: powerquery, data-wrangling

Using powerquery M code, how can I fill in missing values which are required, using the most common value in a group of rows?

For example, starting with this table:

| id | group | attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | AA | example1 | example2 |  |
| 8 | AA |  | example2 |  |
| 9 | AA | example1 | example1 |  |
| 13 | AB | example4 | example2 | example3 |
| 14 | AB | example4 | example2 | example3 |
| 15 | AB |  |  |  |
| 19 | BB |  |  |  |
| 20 | BB | example5 |  |  |
| 23 | BB |  |  |  |

I wanted to repair attribute 1, so I'd want to end with:

| id | group | attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | AA | example1 | example2 |  |
| 8 | AA | example1 | example2 |  |
| 9 | AA | example1 | example1 |  |
| 13 | AB | example4 | example2 | example3 |
| 14 | AB | example4 | example2 | example3 |
| 15 | AB | example4 |  |  |
| 19 | BB | example5 |  |  |
| 20 | BB | example5 |  |  |
| 23 | BB | example5 |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pass I was going to suggest fill...down... but your data does not lend itself to that.  It seems you are using the most repeated value from the each group to replace the nulls in that group. This will do it

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
// get table of counts  for Attribute 1 by Group
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"group", "attribute 1"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
// take out nulls
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([attribute 1] <> null)),
// Group again, sort on count, add index. The row with index=1 will be the attribute most repeated for the group
#"Grouped rows2" =      Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"group"}, {{"NiceTable", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_,{{"Count", Order.Descending}} ), "Index",1,1), type table}} ),
#"Expanded NiceTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped rows2", "NiceTable", {"attribute 1", "Index"}, {"NiceTable.attribute 1", "NiceTable.Index"}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded NiceTable", each ([NiceTable.Index] = 1)),
// merge this into the orginal table and add custom column to replace blank rows with the most frequent other answer
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"group"},#"Filtered Rows1",{"group"},"FR",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded FR" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "FR", {"NiceTable.attribute 1"}, {"NiceTable.attribute 1"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded FR", "Custom", each if [attribute 1]=null then [NiceTable.attribute 1] else [attribute 1])
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: What about List.Mode? I just learned about that one, picks the most common value in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the approach below is the right one but as long as the OP does not clarify his post what his issue is it it really difficult to tell, at least for me.

```
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"group", type text}, {"attribute 1", type text}, {"attribute 2", type text}, {"attribute 3", type text}}),
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte" = Table.AddColumn(#"Geänderter Typ", "newAttrib1", each fx2nd([group]))
in
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte"
```

The function fx2nd looks like

```
(group as text) =>
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"group", type text}, {"attribute 1", type text}, {"attribute 2", type text}, {"attribute 3", type text}}),
    #"Gefilterte Zeilen" = Table.SelectRows(#"Geänderter Typ", each ([group] = group)),
    #"Gefilterte Zeilen1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Gefilterte Zeilen", each [attribute 1] <> null),
    #"Beibehaltene erste Zeilen" = Table.FirstN(#"Gefilterte Zeilen1",1),
    #"attribute 1" = #"Beibehaltene erste Zeilen"{0}[attribute 1]
in
    #"attribute 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use the fill down function to do that

```
= Table.FillDown(Source,{"attribute 1"})
```

Comment: Nope, would screw up the grouped attributes.

Comment: What attributes are grouped? Your post is pretty unclear about your issue especially _using the most common value in a group of rows_  is not defined. What is the most common value and what group of rows do you refer to?

Comment: Group is the field that defines the groups, the nulls should have the most common value from attribute 1... per group.